# Are you driving truck?

Tags: idiomatic-language

Let's say I'm in a bar and overhear two guys talking about being on the road and stuff. Could I (as another way of asking them if they are truckers) ask them...

***Are you driving truck?***

Would that be natural too?

Comment: You would want to use a generic present tense, and add an article (_truck_ is a count noun): _Do you drive a truck?_ Using the progressive _are driving_ refers to the present time; if they are truckers in a bar they're not driving at that time.

Comment: @JohnLawler  That should probably be an answer.

Answer (score 2):

It's [common jargon in the trucking world](https://www.alltruckjobs.com/blog/trucker-talk/) to say "drive truck" to mean "drive trucks for a living".

In your situation where you're in a bar, you're asking about someone's profession, not their current activity, so *present simple* is the correct tense:

> **Do** you drive truck?"

https://www.alltruckjobs.com/blog/trucker-talk/

Comment: I'm sure you are right, so +1, but it is quintessentially American - as in ***she teaches school***. In Britain we would almost certainly use an article ***I'm driving a truck*** (meaning - as a job, not necessarily at that moment). But we do get close to that idiom with e.g. ***he is playing football***, ***he plays centre-half for Everton***, ***he is playing cello in the local symphony orchestra***.

Comment: @WS2 I wasn't sure when I first read the question, but "drive truck" fit with something in the parts of my mind that are accessed once every ten years or so. I had to research it to be sure.